# Check if multidimensional array contains array according given array of keys to check

Tags: php, arrays

I have a `Array` containing a set of `Arrays`...

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    array (size=7)
      'BMS' => 
        array (size=2)
          'key' => string 'Boomsoort' (length=9)
          'value' => string 'Naaldhout - gewone den' (length=22)
      'ONT' => 
        array (size=2)
          'key' => string 'Ontwikkelingsfase' (length=17)
          'value' => string 'Middeloud naaldhout (20 - 60j)' (length=30)
      'SLG' => 
        array (size=2)
          'key' => string 'Sluitingsgraad' (length=14)
          'value' => string 'Meer dan 2/3' (length=12)
      'BED' => 
        array (size=2)
          'key' => string 'Bedrijfsvorm' (length=12)
          'value' => string 'Hooghout' (length=8)
      'NISCODE' => 
        array (size=2)
          'key' => string 'Gemeentecode overeenkomstig het NIS' (length=35)
          'value' => string '46021' (length=5)
      'KLASSE' => 
        array (size=2)
          'key' => string 'Bosclassificatie' (length=16)
          'value' => string 'Bos' (length=3)
      'POLNR' => 
        array (size=2)
          'key' => string 'Polygoonnummer' (length=14)
          'value' => string '32239' (length=5)
  1 => 
    array (size=7)
      'BMS' => 
        array (size=2)
          'key' => string 'Boomsoort' (length=9)
          'value' => string 'Loofhout - eik of Amerikaanse eik' (length=33)
      'ONT' => 
        array (size=2)
          'key' => string 'Ontwikkelingsfase' (length=17)
          'value' => string '10' (length=2)
      'SLG' => 
        array (size=2)
          'key' => string 'Sluitingsgraad' (length=14)
          'value' => string 'Meer dan 2/3' (length=12)
      'BED' => 
        array (size=2)
          'key' => string 'Bedrijfsvorm' (length=12)
          'value' => string 'Hooghout' (length=8)
      'NISCODE' => 
        array (size=2)
          'key' => string 'Gemeentecode overeenkomstig het NIS' (length=35)
          'value' => string '46021' (length=5)
      'KLASSE' => 
        array (size=2)
          'key' => string 'Bosclassificatie' (length=16)
          'value' => string 'Bos' (length=3)
      'POLNR' => 
        array (size=2)
          'key' => string 'Polygoonnummer' (length=14)
          'value' => string '32239' (length=5)
```

I also have an `Array` that holds a list of `Array` keys that should be used to check the main `Array` (definition above) upon adding a new entry. If these key / values already excist - I don't want to add the item to the main `Array`. If one or more key / values does not excist ... the array can be added to the main collection.

```
  array (size=7)
    'BMS',       
    'ONT',     
    'SLG',
    'BED',      
    'NISCODE',        
    'KLASSE',     
    'POLNR'
```

**Situation 1** ; adding a `Array`that already excists on all defined keys.

```
array (size=7)
  'BMS' => 
    array (size=2)
      'key' => string 'Boomsoort' (length=9)
      'value' => string 'Loofhout - eik of Amerikaanse eik' (length=33)
  'ONT' => 
    array (size=2)
      'key' => string 'Ontwikkelingsfase' (length=17)
      'value' => string '10' (length=2)
  'SLG' => 
    array (size=2)
      'key' => string 'Sluitingsgraad' (length=14)
      'value' => string 'Meer dan 2/3' (length=12)
  'BED' => 
    array (size=2)
      'key' => string 'Bedrijfsvorm' (length=12)
      'value' => string 'Hooghout' (length=8)
  'NISCODE' => 
    array (size=2)
      'key' => string 'Gemeentecode overeenkomstig het NIS' (length=35)
      'value' => string '46021' (length=5)
  'KLASSE' => 
    array (size=2)
      'key' => string 'Bosclassificatie' (length=16)
      'value' => string 'Bos' (length=3)
  'POLNR' => 
    array (size=2)
      'key' => string 'Polygoonnummer' (length=14)
      'value' => string '32239' (length=5)
```

**Situation 2** ; adding a `Array`that does not excists on all defined keys. Note that the `BMS`key has a `value` that the main collection does not know yet.

```
array (size=7)
  'BMS' => 
    array (size=2)
      'key' => string 'Boomsoort' (length=9)
      'value' => string 'Unadded value' (length=33)
  'ONT' => 
    array (size=2)
      'key' => string 'Ontwikkelingsfase' (length=17)
      'value' => string '10' (length=2)
  'SLG' => 
    array (size=2)
      'key' => string 'Sluitingsgraad' (length=14)
      'value' => string 'Meer dan 2/3' (length=12)
  'BED' => 
    array (size=2)
      'key' => string 'Bedrijfsvorm' (length=12)
      'value' => string 'Hooghout' (length=8)
  'NISCODE' => 
    array (size=2)
      'key' => string 'Gemeentecode overeenkomstig het NIS' (length=35)
      'value' => string '46021' (length=5)
  'KLASSE' => 
    array (size=2)
      'key' => string 'Bosclassificatie' (length=16)
      'value' => string 'Bos' (length=3)
  'POLNR' => 
    array (size=2)
      'key' => string 'Polygoonnummer' (length=14)
      'value' => string '32239' (length=5)
```

I'm looking for the best way of checking the main `Array` collection if it already contains an `Array` where the keys needed to be checked are given by an other `Array`.

I've tried looping the 3 `Arrays` to check with each other - the code I've created is quite robust and big. I would like to see some fresh tries that can lead me in reducing the lines of code... Pseudo code for what I have

```
/**
* @Param collection = Global collection
* @Param requirekeystocheck = Array keys to check for excistance
* @Param arraytoadd = Array to be added
* @return Boolean
*/
Function checkExcistArrayOfKeysForArray($collection, $requirekeystocheck, $arraytoadd){
    Loop main Array $collection as $collectionItem
        Loop Array $requirekeystocheck with keys to check as $uniqueKey
            Check if main $collectionItem[$uniqueKey] contains $arraytoadd[$uniqueKey] 
                Check if the values are equal (already present)

    If all values in $requirekeystocheck excist in $collectionItem - the item that needs to be added already excists. 
        Return TRUE 
    If not all values excist - the item can be added
        Return TRUE

}
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about using a php class. This all looks like it could be replaced pretty easily by such. The class could look like this:

```
class myClass {

    public $bms = '';
    public $ont = '';
    public $slg = '';
    public $bed = '';
    public $niscode = '';
    public $klasse = '';
    public $polnr = '';

    function __construct($cData) {
        $this->bms = $cData[0];
        $this->ont = $cData[1];
        $this->slg = $cData[2];
        $this->bed = $cData[3];
        $this->niscode = $cData[4];
        $this->klasse = $cData[5];
        $this->polnr = $cData[6]
    }

    function equals($obj) {
        // this function receives another instance of the class and checks whether both instances are identical
        if ($obj->bms != $this->bms) { return false; }
        if ($obj->ont!= $this->ont) { return false; }
        if ($obj->slg != $this->slg) { return false; }
        if ($obj->bed != $this->bed) { return false; }
        if ($obj->niscode != $this->niscode) { return false; }
        if ($obj->klasse != $this->klasse) { return false; }
        if ($obj->polnr != $this->polnr) { return false; }
        return true;
    }

}
```

The only thing I am unsure about is the little array with "key" and "value", that you use all the time. Is there no way to get rid of it? I cannot tell, because I don't know the purpose of these values. If you explain their sense, I might imagine another one. If this is impossible, better make another class for it (similar to a datatype):

```
class myDatatype {

    public $key = '';
    public $value = '';

    public construct __construct($key, $value) 
        $this->key = $key;
        $this->value = $value;
    }

}
```

All varibles in myClass get then as data an instance of myClass, like the following:

```
$example->bms = new myDatatype("Bomsoort", "Somewhat");
```

The way of adding new values to the class depends on the type the variables of "myClass" are of. The following example assumes that you used the solution via "myDatatype":

```
$data = array(/* bms */ new myDatatype("key", "value"), ..., /* polnr */ myDatatype("key", "value"));
$example = new myClass($data);
```

As this can become quite confusing, think about another function, that takes all necessary values and does exactly what I wrote above.
thingy = new myClass($data);

Comment: Thanks for you input. The key values are dynamic... they differ according the context. I would need dynamic way to check... without defining the keys as class parameters....

Comment: Could you describe the problem you want to solve with it? If the keys of the Sub-Arrays ('BMS' etc.) need to be dynamic, what about a class with one associative Array as variable? The keys of this array are 'BMS etc., the values of it are the data represented by myDatatype. Advantage: You could write functions returning all indeces of the array, checks whether another object is equal or easily creates everything with the given data

Answer (score 0):

Try array search method to search array with array_column
Refer bellow solution of adding item to cart using session

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $pr_id = $_REQUEST['id'];
 $quantity = isset($_REQUEST['quantity'])?$_REQUEST['quantity']:1;
 if(isset($_REQUEST['action']) && $_REQUEST['action']=='add')
{
  if(isset($_SESSION['cartitems']))
  {
     //find index of an array if it exits then do not add else add to cart and then
    if (!array_key_exists($pr_id,$_SESSION['cartitems']))
    {
        $_SESSION['cartitems'][$pr_id]['id'] = $pr_id;
        $_SESSION['cartitems'][$pr_id]['quantity'] = $quantity;
    }
   }
  else
  {
    $_SESSION['cartitems'][$pr_id]['id'] = $pr_id;
    $_SESSION['cartitems'][$pr_id]['quantity'] = $quantity;     
  }
  $arr = array();
  $arr['count'] = count($_SESSION['cartitems']);
  $arr['message'] = 'Item successFully added';
  echo json_encode($arr);
 }
```